# Basics of Quadratic Sieve algorithm

Tags: prime-numbers, factoring, prime-factorization, quadratic-residues

I'm trying to understand Quadratic Sieve algorithm for integer factorization, I follow the description in the book "Prime Numbers" by Crandall and Pomerance, specifically the Algorithm 6.1.1. (Even though the question below apply to any description of QS, as far as I can see.)

Please, I have a few very basic questions about the method:

- in the initialization phase one finds the square roots ($a_i$) on the number being factored ($N$) modulo some prime ($p_i$). But in the description the roots are never mentioned again, what are they good for?
- sieve phase, this is possibly just me not understanding the text fully, that I should "sieve for $B$-smooth values". I think it is possible to read the "smooth" word that I have to try all the primes up to the bound, but I think what is meant here that I only should try the primes having Legendre symbol equal to one, from the previous phase. (I try both and there was no difference..?)
- why do I have to have $(K+1) \times K$ matrix in the linear algebra step ($K$ is the number of primes found during the initialization)? I mean, if I got lucky I could end up having just three exponent vectors summing to zero vector so I assume it is because the algorithm uses linear algebra method to find the right subset, correct?
- in the final step, what to do if the GCD does not reveal non-trivial factor? Simply compute more exponent vectors for the linear algebra step? Remove some of the already computed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(1)$ The purpose of the roots is to accelerate the search for numbers $x$ with the property that $\ \ x^2\mod N\ \ $ has small factors. The algorithm would also work for random numbers, but the quadratic residues are a significant improvement concerning speed.

$(2)$ A number is $B$-smooth , if it has no prime factor larger than $B$. The goal of the number field sieve is to find enough congruences $x^2\equiv y\mod N$ with $B$-smooth $y$

$(3)$ In fact, we could have a zero vector with less than $K$ rows, but the chance will not be very large , if the matrix is large. Moreover, we may need many congruences of the form $\ \ x^2\equiv y^2\mod N\ \ $. Theoretically, there is a chance of $\frac{1}{2}$ that such a congruence gives a non-trivial factor, but the congruences constructed are not random.

$(4)$ It is as you say. In fact, sometimes , no factor is found, some congruences are deleted and new congruences are calculated. I do not know however the details.

Comment: Thank you and please, could you say a bit more on (1) and (2)? (1) I was thinking that the roots are used for acceleration but how and during which phase? The description does not mention this. (2) My question was whether there is any difference if I sieve with all the primes up to $B$ or all the primes up to $B$ having Legendre symbol equal to one?

Comment: $(1)$ If we choose $x$ such that $x^2\mod N$ is divisible by all the primes in the factor base (which can be achieved with the suitable residues), then the chance that $x^2\mod N$ is $B$-smooth increases drastically. $(2)$ The factor base contains the primes $p_i$, such that the congruence $x^2\equiv N\mod p_i$ has a solution. The other prime numbers need not be considered because $x^2\mod N$ cannot be divisible by other primes (upto the given limit) anyway. In other words, it makes no difference, but using all the primes upto the given limit would result in a waste of time.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for being slow here: (1) Let me backtrack a bit: Legendre symbol of one guarantees that for a given prime there is a number which is square (i.e. quadratic residue), correct? The factor base is comprised of such primes because of speed, correct? But why do I need to know the exact two roots of the residue? If you happen to have the book I'm asking about the last line in step 1 ("$\pm a^2_i$"). On other words, where in the algorithm do I make use of the roots?

Comment: @minmax I do not have the book, but I guess that the roots are necessary to determine the suitable values for $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding 1:

The problem is that you want to sieve for presence of prime factors in x * x mod N, with ceil(sqrt( N )) <= x < ceil(sqrt( 2 * N )) and hence x * x mod N = x * x - N, without actually computing the expensive x * x or x * x mod N. The a_i allow this.

The p in 2 < p <= B are searched so that [ a * a = N ] mod p contains 2 solutions a_1 and a_2. The number of solutions of [ a * a = N ] mod p can be zero, one or two. If there is one solution, then p | N, so this typically doesn't happen. The cases of zero and two solutions occur - apparently - with about equal probability.

The x's are sieved based on [ x = a_i ] mod p, hence augmenting s and t in x = a_1 + s * p and x = a_2 + t * p.

For such x, it holds that [ x * x mod N ] mod p = [ a_i * a_i + 2 * p * a_i + p * p - N ] mod p = [ a_i * a_i - N ] mod p = 0.

Conversely, any x can be written as x = q * p + r. What does [ x * x mod N ] mod p = 0 tell us about r?

It holds that 0 = [ x * x mod N ] mod p = [ x * x - N ] mod p = [ q * q * p * p + 2 * p * q * r + r * r - N ] mod p = [ r * r - N ] mod p.